# Add pending for reply comment in console WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, comments

How to add pending option for reply comment in console WordPress. I made an image with a visually demonstrated option.

Reply to a comment, but keep it in "pending" status. Not a comment left by a visitor, but a comment written by an administrator in the WP Admin.

[image]

Sorry for my English.

I would like an answer to my question.